# How to convert a column with list of numbers to np.array format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to convert all rows of a column to numpy array format in a pandas dataframe? A sample dataframe:
[image]

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
        "actual":["1,0,0,1","0,0,1,0"],
        "predicted":["[1,0,0,0]","[0,1,1,1]"]
    })
```

Ideal data frame:

[image]

I tried to convert the `actual` column to array format using the code below but failed.

```
df['actual']=df.actual(lambda x: np.array([int(s) for s in x.to_numpy().split(',')]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes because of `df.actual(` you call on the column itself, like `df['actual'](`, you may use `Series.apply` and `to_numpy` doesn't exists on a `str`

```
df['actual'] = df.actual.apply(lambda x: np.array([int(s) for s in x.split(',')]))

         actual  predicted
0  [1, 0, 0, 1]  [1,0,0,0]
1  [0, 0, 1, 0]  [0,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the 'apply' function in the series. And you don't have to call `.to_numpy()`

`df['actual']=df.actual.apply(lambda x: np.array([int(s) for s in x.split(',')]))`